# Pine Script Strategy tester opens positions late

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I am trying to write a simple strategy backtest script in pine. I am using Heikin Ashi candles chart. The strategy tester is working 1 candle late. At close of each candle I check if previous candle was white. If it was white I want to take entry at open of this new candle but strategy tester is opening trade at close of this new candle. Which is 1 candle late. Same issue when strategy exit (check image for more info).
How can I change this behaviour? If strategy tester cannot do, can we do it with alerts?

```
strategy(title="c",shorttitle = "c", overlay = true , initial_capital = 1000, default_qty_type = strategy.cash, default_qty_value = 1000, process_orders_on_close =true)
```

I want to take entry if previous candle was white

```
if close[1] > open[1]
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, when = close)
```

Similarly I want to close if previous candle was red

```
if close[1] < open[1]
strategy.close("Long", when = close)
```

The strategy is working as described in below image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using `process_orders_on_close =true` in your `strategy()` call. As the name suggests it will process your orders on bar close.

You should remove that from your `strategy()` call and than check if the current bar is white. It will then execute your order on the opening of the next bar.

```
if close > open
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, when = close)
```